# VisualForce RSS using Custom Object with Custom Controller

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-controller

I am attempting to create an RSS feed of Salesforce activity similar to the example seen [here](https://gist.github.com/greenstork/6032843). The Salesforce content I am trying to pull in lives under a custom object with an API Name of `Articles__Custom_Content__c`.

I am writing the custom controller, but I'm having trouble knowing which names to reference in it from the custom object.

Below is my current code based on the example linked above. When I attempt to save this, I get the error `Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Article' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`

The `Article` name is one that I made up. I'm not sure what field I should be inserting here to make it work. Can anyone provide some guidance?

```
public without sharing class RSSContentController {

    public List<Articles__Custom_Content__c> articles { get; private set; }

    public RSSContentController() {
        this.articles = new List <Articles__Custom_Content__c>();

        List <Article> articlelist = [SELECT Name, Articles__Title__c, Articles__Text__c, Articles__Is_Published__c FROM Article WHERE Articles__Is_Published__c = "True" LIMIT 50];

        for (Article singleArticle : articlelist) {
            articles.add(new Articles__Custom_Content__c(singleArticle.Name, singleArticle.Articles__Title__c, singleArticle.Articles__Text__c));
        }
    }

    public class Articles__Custom_Content__c {
        public String name { get; private set; }
        public String title { get; private set; }
        public String description { get; private set; }

        public Articles__Custom_Content__c(String name, String title, String description) {
            this.name = name != null ? name.escapeXml() : null;
            this.title = title != null ? title.escapeXml() : null;
            this.description = description != null ? description.escapeXml(): null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the API name all the way down. Just replace all instances of `Article` in your code with `Articles__Custom_Content__c`. As an aside, you can't use `__` in a class name, so you'll need to change *those* `Articles__Custom_Content__c` to something like `ArticleContentWrapper`.

```
public without sharing class RSSContentController {

    public List<ArticleContentWrapper> articles { get; private set; }

    public RSSContentController() {
        this.articles = new List <ArticleContentWrapper>();

        List <Articles__Custom_Content__c> articlelist = [SELECT Name, Articles__Title__c, Articles__Text__c, Articles__Is_Published__c FROM Articles__Custom_Content__c WHERE Articles__Is_Published__c = True LIMIT 50];

        for (Articles__Custom_Content__c singleArticle : articlelist) {
            articles.add(new ArticleContentWrapper(singleArticle.Name, singleArticle.Articles__Title__c, singleArticle.Articles__Text__c));
        }
    }

    public class ArticleContentWrapper {
        public String name { get; private set; }
        public String title { get; private set; }
        public String description { get; private set; }

        public ArticleContentWrapper(String name, String title, String description) {
            this.name = name != null ? name.escapeXml() : null;
            this.title = title != null ? title.escapeXml() : null;
            this.description = description != null ? description.escapeXml(): null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! On another note, do you know how I would be able to pull Salesforce Topics into this RSS feed? Users currently have the ability to add Topics to this custom object, but I can not figure out how to pull in which Topics are attached.

Comment: You'll want to query the [TopicAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_topicassignment.htm) object. Personally, I have never used this object, but it looks fairly straight forward.

Comment: @user994585 The query looks like `select id, (select id, topic.name from topicassignments) from Articles__Custom_Content__c`.